# How to create a default lvm pool on lxd v3

Tags: lvm, lxd

The expected

```
lxc storage create default lvm lvm.thinpool_name=lvdata lvm.vg_name=vghdd lvm.use_thinpool=true
```

fails with the

```
Error: LXD already uses volume group "vghdd" for pool "default"
```

while LXD certainly does not use it - it's a new LXD installation and

```
lxd sql "select * from storage_pools_config"
```

certainly returns nothing.

`vghdd` volume group exists, `lvdata` thinpool exists. `lvdata` is not empty - there are couple volumes created there already, but it was not a problem for lxd v2.x

From the other hand, if I specify the non existing thinpool name:

```
# lxc storage create default lvm lvm.vg_name=vghdd lvm.thinpool_name=lvlxd lvm.use_thinpool=true
Error: volume group "vghdd" is not empty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And to answer my own question:

thanks to the project maintainers I could find that the original command is "wrong"

The correct one should use `source` as a volume group name.

```
lxc storage create pool1 lvm source=<vg_name> lvm.thinpool_name=<thinpool_name>
```